# nginx rewrite link with wordpress

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I have broken link on my WP blog, which is on this route

```
www.site.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1
```

But when I want to redirect it to completly new site, my rewrite rule doesnt work. I used this

```
  rewrite ^(/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1)(.*)$   http://link.com/my.pdf$2 permanent;
```

Comment: Now I also tryed location = /wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1 {
  return 301 http://link.com/my.pdf;
}

Comment: Anything from `?` onwards is part of the query string and cannot be considered in the location or rewrite rule. You may need to use an `if` block to test `$arg_id`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I want specific links with specific ID redirect to specific URLS :-)

Comment: If you want to redirect multiple IDs use a map. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment you have tried:

```
location = /wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1 { 
    return 301 link.com/my.pdf;
}
```

This will not work because the `location` rule cannot test the query string component of the URL.

The `if` block can be used for simple tests, such as testing the value of the `$arg_id` which is set to the value of the `id` parameter in the query string. For example:

```
location = /wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php {
    if ($arg_id = 1) {
        return 301 link.com/my.pdf;
    }
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    ...
}
```

Notice that the `location` block above will process any URL specifying the same `download.php` script (that is with values of `id` other than `1`). The `fastcgi` directives are *duplicated* from your `location ~ \.php$` block in order to execute the `download.php` script normally with values of `id` other than `1`.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for more.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!


I used this:
`location = /wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php {
    if ($arg_id = 1) {
        return 301 link.com/my.pdf` but now I have this error



`invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.com.vhost`

Comment: Maybe the error is refering to a different location directive. The code above compiles without error.